# Is it possible to make an instance of SharedPreferences a member of a class?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it OK to initialize `SharedPreferences` this way?

```
void main() async {
  GetIt.instance.registerSingletonAsync<LocalStorageService>;
  ...


class LocalStorageService {
  late final SharedPreferences _prefs;

  LocalStorageService() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((v) => _prefs = v); //?
  }
```

The recommendew way of initializing `SharedPreferences` is

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

But it's not possible to use await and async in constructor of `LocalStorageService`.

Comment: SharedPreferences is sync for getting once you've initialized it.  I just create a global "prefs" variable and initialize it in main before runApp.  Not sure why people keep making this harder than it should be.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz it can work this way I suppose

Comment: @RandalSchwartz that's because I use SharedPreferences exclusively in LocalStorageService so it's more logical to keep and initialize it there

Comment: Then have something you're calling from an async main to initialize it and wait for it, before you call runApp.